# How can I buff my hardwood floors without a machine?

Tags: hardwood-floor, staining

My portable AC leaked some water and left behind some white stains on my hardwood floor. Over a few hours, they slowly began to disappear away, but the floor could use some touching up.

I read that I should use #000 steel wool with wax, but online I also found this [buffing trigger spray](http://www.parish-supply.com/flashback-spray-buffing-compound.aspx) solution.

[image]

I don't have any kind of machine for buffing and honestly, I don't really know the difference between waxing and buffing, I know waxing goes after buffing. I have also read that mineral spirits could help too, but I'm not sure what they actually do to the floor.

My question is, should I use the steel wool with wax, and if so what wax?  Or should I use this buffing spray, but how can I buff manually, since I don't have a machine?

Comment: I can't post a photo, because I don't have rep 10 yet. There is no longer a stain, but the floor has curled slightly, looks more worn out and I would like to polish it.   I don't know how to figure out what the finish is, but it is brand new. The floor itself is old, but the finish is new. I cannot put my fingernail between the boards, so it is some kind of glossy thick cover.

Comment: If white 'stain' started to go away after merely a few hours, I'd wait a week or two to see if the problem entirely fixes itself without intervention.

Comment: Hopefully this image shows: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2GRsr.jpg